# Change Font color on scroll down

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-statements

In over my head...help.  I need to create code to change the font color in A4 to white when a user scrolls down to row 15.

Or is there a conditional formatting formula I could use instead?

This is my failed attempt:

```
Sub ChangeFontColor()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Test" Then
If ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows(15) Then
Range("A4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to change the color? When Row 15 is visible? The Row 15 is the Top Row? When the Active cell is in Row 15? And what is the idea to set a cell to white if it is possibly not visible at all?

Comment: When user hits row 15  and beyond-- A4 in the frozen header row no longer applies.  I would like just that cell to white out, and when the user scrolls above row15 it would change to black font.  The actual spreadsheet I'm working on has a lot more rows that what my sample shows. Here is my 2nd attempt.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

      If Not Intersect(Range("A25"), ActiveWindow.VisibleRange) Is Nothing Then
         Range("A4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
      Else
         Range("A4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      End If

End Sub